# Gridview - Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control

Tags: asp.net

the problem comes from:

double dItemPremium = (Eval("Premium")!= DBNull.Value) ? (double)(Eval("Premium")) : 0;

and I need help changing it.

I am working with a Gridview.

```
protected void dgCustomer_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            Label pLabel = new Label();
            double dItemPremium = (Eval("Premium")!= DBNull.Value) ? (double)(Eval("Premium")) : 0;
            pLabel.Text = dItemPremium.ToString("0.00");
            dTotal_m += dItemPremium;

        dgCustomer.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        dgCustomer.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        dgCustomer.FooterRow.Controls.Add(pLabel);

    }


    protected void dgCustomer_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 

        dTotal_m += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Premium"));

        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Totals:";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = dTotal_m.ToString("0.00");

            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

In HTML I used

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(DataItem,"Premium")%></ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Premium Amount Paid</HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I added DataBinder and DataItem but still nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access bound values in code behind using the controls. Eval, Bind, etc methods are to be used to bind values to controls. There are many ways to access bound values in code bebind, one of them is

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text
```

another is putting bound value in Label and accessing it like,

```
string tempstr=((Label)dgCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[<cell_number>].FindControl("Label_ID")).Text;
```

Comment: @user3508633 I am Pleased for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone have this problem, here is another solution: on the aspx file change from <%# to <%=

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <%= DataBinder.Eval(DataItem,"Premium")%></ItemTemplate>
<HeaderTemplate>
```